# Can I plot a time-series with boolean variable?

Tags: python, boolean, time-series

I have a dataset which has a date variable, and a boolean variable.

The date variable has already been broken down into 'Year' and 'month'. So I have 2 fields corresponding to the date. And the boolean indicates if that particular record is late(1) or not(0).

Here is a snapshot of the data:

```
Date(Index) Date_Year_Key   Date_Month_Key  Is_Late

2014-01-01  2014        1       1
2014-01-03  2014        1       1
2014-01-03  2014        1       1
2014-01-03  2014        1       1
```

I want to plot the data with time to see if any trend or pattern exists in the data(orders) being late or not and if I can predict the future orders using time-series modeling.

I have tried plotting the data using an aggregate function.

[image: plot of late orders]

```
temp=big_cust_tm_series.groupby(['Date_Year_Key', 'Date_Month_Key'])['Is_Late'].mean() 
temp.plot(figsize=(15,5),
          title= 'Late records(Monthwise)', fontsize=14)
```

Also, I tried this following code but it gave me an error.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm 
sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(temp).plot() 
result = sm.tsa.stattools.adfuller(temp) 
plt.show()

AttributeError: 'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'inferred_freq'
```

I don't see any increasing or decreasing trend in the plot, nor any patterns. So I am not sure even if this is a proper example to do time-series analysis or not

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by noting that I'm more of a general stats person and don't know much about time series modelling. 
 also that "binomial data" like this isn't very informative, so you need a surprising amount to detect changes.  e.g. with 300 rows and your mean of 0.05 we'd expect a standard deviation of `sqrt(0.05 * (1-0.05) / 300)` = ~0.013, so we'd expect to see values around `0.05 +-2 * 0.013` = (0.024, 0.076).

what you're plotting looks sensible, but I'd suggest "truncating" the date at the month, rather than working with `(year, month)` tuples, as it's easier to turn into plots nicely.  for example, if you have a [`datetime64`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html) column called `Date` in a Pandas dataframe called `df`, you could do:

```
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('M').dt.start_time
```

the `dt`s are annoying, but signal the desire to work with [datetime like properies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html). after doing this, you can do your plot as before:

```
plt.plot(df.groupby('Month')['Is_Late'].mean())
```

and you'll get date labels on the x-axis.  note that your plot is basically in line with the maths at the top (i.e. lowest value is around 0.03 and largest is around 0.08).

I'm not aware of being able to set a ["link function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Link_function) on any of the `statsmodels` time series analysis stuff, which means you probably can't do much what that.  that said, you might get some mileage out of using a "generalised linear model" on your data, for example:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

df['month'] = df.Date.dt.month
df['dayofweek'] = df.Date.dt.dayofweek

mod = smf.glm('Is_Late ~ C(dayofweek) + C(month)', df2, family=sm.families.Binomial())
res = mod.fit()
res.summary()
```

would allow you to fit a "day of the week" effect to the data.  note that this would have shown up on your above aggregation/plot by adding noise.  also note that in general fitting timeseries data with a regression like the above is not recommended, but given your use of statsmodels and the lack of an obvious way of giving a link function this serves as a low-tech fallback

note that there are a lot more stats/time-series related packages/code available for the programming language "R"

Comment: Thank you Sam ! :)